# Trying to limit number of tweets returned by a program

Tags: python, twitter

The code I am using is this.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib2 as urllib

# See assignment1.html instructions or README for how to get these credentials

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
access_token_key = ""
access_token_secret = ""

_debug = 0

oauth_token    = oauth.Token(key=access_token_key, secret=access_token_secret)
oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()

http_method = "GET"


http_handler  = urllib.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)

Construct, sign, and open a twitter request
using the hard-coded credentials above.
'''
def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                             token=oauth_token,
                                             http_method=http_method,
                                             http_url=url,
                                             parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if http_method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response

def fetchsamples():
  url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json?"
  parameters = ['en']
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  for line in response:
    print (line.strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fetchsamples()
```

So this just streams a constant stream of tweets.  I would like to limit this to 100.  I tried adding ?count=100 to the url but the count parameter is not allowed for statuses/sample.json.  Any help would be greatly apprecited.  Thanks.

Comment: It is somewhat unwise to share your tokens and secrets.

Comment: I edited them out.

Comment: Yes, but: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45067310/1. You should reset/recreate them via Twitter.

Comment: Why not just break out of your ```for line in response:```loop after 100 iterations?

Comment: Or `for line in response[:100]:`

Comment: Wow, thank you.  So simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like my comment worked for you, here it is an an answer.

replace this

```
for line in response:
```

with this

```
for line in response[:100]:
```